# Using MYSQL Like '"%$*%"' to create a search Filter

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a search on two tables using MYSQL join now i want to go about filtering some variables i have called up from the database.

this sql query gets everything and pastes on my screen

```
$sql2 = "select pinfo.*, einfo.* 
from profile_info pinfo , education_info einfo
where pinfo.username = einfo.username";
```

Now i want to filter some variables, say fullname, date of birth, gender,location and resume,institution_name

Now information is saved on two tables i have a problem writing this exact query to filter the two tables are

profile_info
education_info

profile_info has this columns
    username

```
file_name   

file_size   

file_type       

tmp_name    

photograph_name     

photograph_size 

photograph_type                         

photographtmp_name                          

fullname                            

address     
address2
city                    
state                           

email                           

tel                         

state_origin                            

lga                         

marital_status                          

dob
```

And education info has this columns

```
    username            
    inst_name           
    inst_name2          
    grade           
    study_course                

    qualification           
    other_qualification         

    completion_year
```

Now using LIKE in MYSQL How can i be able to filter to get adequate results.

Code i have written so far looks like this

```
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['search_button']))
            {
                require_once('inc/config.php');
                $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ('Cannot Connect: '.mysqli_error());
                $sql = "select ";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
                while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ){

                    echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td width=248 align=center>
                        <font face=Verdana size=2>".$row['fullname']."</font></td>
                        <td align=center><font face=Verdana size=2>".$row['dob']."</font></td>
                        <td align=center><font face=Verdana size=2>".$row['gender']."</font></td>
                        <td align=center><font face=Verdana size=2>".$row['location']."</font></td>
                        <td align=center><font face=Verdana size=2>
                        ".$row['resume']."</font></td>
                    </tr>";


                }

            }



            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS.

Example taking fullname, address from profile_info and grade and qualification from education_info

```
       $sql2 = "select profile_info.fullname as n, 
    profile_info.address as a, 
    education_info.grade as g, 
    eduction_info.qualification as q 
from profile_info inner join education info on profile_info.username=education_info.username";
```